# Press Enter Instead of Clicking Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a skeleton of a program that I want to use:

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = Tk()

def program():
    print('Hello')

tex=Text(root)
tex.pack(side='right')
inputfield = Entry(root)
inputfield.pack(side='bottom')
text = inputfield.get()
but = Button(root,text="Enter", command = program) 
but.pack(side='bottom')

root.mainloop()
```

Alright so recapping, the program is just a frame with a text field, input field and a button that says `Enter`. I want to call the program the button calls without actually pressing the button. I want to input the text in the input field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on my keyboard to call the function.

Is that possible through tkinter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You only have to bind the Entry widget with the event `<Return>`:

```
inputfield.bind('<Return>', lambda _: program())
```

Since the callback function used in `bind` receives one argument (a Tkinter event), you cannot use the reference to `program` directly. So instead of changing the definition of the function, you can use a lambda and name the first argument as `_`, a [common name for "don't care" variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python).

Comment: If you're going to use some "magic" syntax (the underscore as an argument to lambda), your answer would be much more useful if you explained why that was (or wasn't) necessary. You don't want a beginner to just blindly start using this convention without knowing what it does.

Comment: @BryanOakley so what is the difference between the underscore and using "lambda: funcName()" ?

Comment: @Jona: the lambda requires an argument, so `lambda: funcName()` would throw an error. My point was, using the unconventional argument name `_` is less clear than the more common name `event`.

Comment: ah ha, brilliantly simply explained. thanks @BryanOakley